# OneHotEncoder causes Type error during data preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I'm developing an intent classification service, but, I have faced an error below this.
I've followed [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-introduction-to-intent-classification-96fda6b1f557), but I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

Below is my code. and It's in the article, that I've mentioned above

```py
def max_length(words):
    return len(max(words, key = len))


def encoding_doc(token, words):
    return token.texts_to_sequences(words)

def padding_doc(encoded_doc, max_length):
    return pad_sequences(encoded_doc, maxlen = max_length, padding = "post")

def one_hot(encode):
    o = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    return o.fit_transform(encode)

intent, unique_intent, sentences = load_dataset()
print(sentences[:5])

cleaned_words = cleaning_sentences(sentences)
print(len(cleaned_words))
print(cleaned_words[:2])

word_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(cleaned_words)
vocab_size = len(word_tokenizer.word_index) + 1
max_length = max_length(cleaned_words)

print("Vocab Size = %d and Maximum length = %d" % (vocab_size, max_length))

encoded_doc = encoding_doc(word_tokenizer, cleaned_words)
padded_doc = padding_doc(encoded_doc, max_length)
print(padded_doc[:5])

print("Shape of padded docs = ", padded_doc.shape)

output_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(unique_intent)
print(output_tokenizer.word_index)

encoded_output = encoding_doc(output_tokenizer, intent)
encoded_output = np.array(encoded_output).reshape(-1, 1)

output_one_hot = one_hot(encoded_output)
print(output_one_hot)
```

Comment: You have a `TypeError`, meaning a value in the data you are transforming is not of an expected type, in this case it is not a string or a number. Can you inspect the data ? I suspect you have a missing value somewhere, e.g. a `NaN`.

Comment: @k88 that's quite accurate! then I need to delete NaN values Thx for commenting

Comment: @k88 fillna is not working. I think there's a problem with the data. thank you for commenting again

Comment: Try to discover which row is causing the exception. One way to do so would be to loop through the column and print the type of each cell, there is likely some form of type inconsistency that is easily overlooked. 

Do note that `fillna` returns a dataframe so you have to store it to a variable (or overwrite your current one). Alternatively you can use the arg `inplace=True`. Otherwise you'd still be using the dataframe with missing values.